# Some customer dimensiosn are not ready when GA pageview tags fires

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, ab-testing, vwo

I have a GTM variable that contains the info based on the A/B testing tool VWO.
This variable feeds a GA event tag + a GA pageview Tag, both in GTM.

The GA event tag works like a charm. The GA pageview Tag doesn't.

Yet, the VWO variable is supposed to be loaded first in the page, right? Therefore I would except to have the GTM variable set and ready when the GA pageview tag is fired.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you firing it as both an event and a pageview custom dimension? What scope is the custom dimension? If you have it set at session, then you only need to fire the event.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why it doesn't work. I initially wanted to set up the custom dimension with the pageview. Seeing that it didn't work, I tried with an event... which worked. Fine, yet why?

Comment: Its because through the GTM integration, the variation information is not available until page load. At that point, VWO sends a dataLayer push event, for you to trigger your event off, which then captures the variation information.

Comment: thanks :) And do you know how I can find out next time the order/timing of each js -or at least datalayer or GTM - variables ? I can't find a way to track that, yet this would solve all my issues..